# Como trabalhar com o hasClass em JQuery e adicionar uma classe aos valores encontrados?

Tags: jquery

Em JQuery, após fazer a busca com o `hasClass()`, como eu adiciono uma classe aos elementos encontrados? Com `$(this)`?

No exemplo abaixo que tentei reproduzir para explicar a minha dúvida, busquei com o `hasClass()` elementos que tenham a classe `filtro1_1` ou `filtro2_2` e adicionei uma classe para pintar elas de uma outra cor, ou seja, apenas o **notícia 3 3** não deveria ser pintada, qual a forma correta de trabalhar?

```js
function filtra(){
  if($('.noticia').hasClass('filtro1_1') || $('.noticia').hasClass('filtro2_2')){
    $(this).addClass('pinta_noticia');
  }
}
filtra();
```

```css
.pinta_noticia{
  color: #d71f0b;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="noticia filtro1_1 filtro2_2">
  Notícia 1 2
</div>
<div class="noticia filtro1_1 filtro2_1">
  Notícia 1 1
</div>
<div class="noticia filtro1_3 filtro2_3">
  Notícia 3 3
</div>
```

Comment: Vai entender essa comunidade podre, a mesma pergunta no stackoverflow.com me rendeu 6 pontos positivos e 7 respostas....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui fazendo assim:

```
function filtra() {
  $('.noticia').each(function() {
    if($(this).hasClass('filtro1_1') || $(this).hasClass('filtro2_2')){
      $(this).addClass('pinta_noticia');
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Não entendi bem o motivo de você usar `hasClass`. Essa função serve para verificar se, em uma lista de elementos, que você definiu anteriormente usando um seletor, algum deles possui a classe especificada. Se a lista tem vários elementos, ela retorna true caso qualquer um deles possua a classe.

No seu caso, parece que você quer simplesmente aplicar uma nova classe a itens que já possuem outra classe. Então seria mais simples fazer assim:

```
function filtra(){
  $('.noticia.filtro1_1').addClass('pinta_noticia');
  $('.noticia.filtro2_2').addClass('pinta_noticia');
}
filtra();
```

Repare que os seletores usados já incluem as duas classes (noticia e filtro_x_x), portanto a lista retornada só incluirá elementos que possuam ambas.